# C#: How can I read characters like 'éóú' and öäü in one file?

Tags: c#, json, localization, encode

I am creating a language system for my project where you can easily add a `{language}.json` into a `lang-folder`, and the program includes the language.

At the moment I have German and English as `json` files, named `en-us.json` and `de-de.json` respectively. When I add a test file called `fr-fr.json` for the French language, I encountered a problem where, with the normal `Encoding.Default`, the `é ó ú` characters were shown as `Ã©`. For example, the sentence "Le fichier Excel est créé automatiquement:" instead looks like "Le fichier Excel est crÃ©Ã© automatiquement:".

When I changed the encoding to `Encoding.UTF8`, the French language is shown correctly, but then the German `äöü` characters were replaced with �. So the sentence "Wählen Sie die Excel" now reads as "W�hlen Sie die Excel".

I tried this with a `for` loop:

```cs
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            break;

        case 2:
            encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            break;

        default:
            encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            break;
    }

// Below I try to create an object of the JSON
…
}
```

But that didn't fix my problem since that `for` loop is for characters like Chinese logograms, where `JsonConvert` has problems if it's not in Unicode.

I don't want to say "if the language is French, encode in UTF8; if it's Chinese, use Unicode; etc." since the languages can all be optional and, therefore, you don't need to have a `fr-fr.json`. But if you create a `ru-ru.json`, for example, you need Unicode again.

Is there a way to detect the best encoding for the text? And, second, is there an encoding that could give me both `äöü` and `éóúá…`, so I don't need to manually change it for every language that is faulty?

Comment: Why not use UTF-8 all the way through? In your input files, in your program, in your terminal...

Comment: Ultimately, you need to know what encoding the file was written with. There's a non-zero chance that you actually irretrievably corrupted the data *when it was written* if you are ever using things like `Encoding.Default` or any specific non-unicode code-page encoding. Can you perhaps tell us what the **bytes** are in the file? that might help us determine things. And if possible: always write and read files with a known encoding - UTF-8 should be your default choice. UTF-8 can express any unicode character you will encounter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your text editor saved your `fr-fr.json` as UTF-8 and your `de-de.json` as Latin-1 (aka "Default" on your system).

The solution is to save *all* your JSON files as UTF-8 (since UTF-8 can encode all Unicode characters and has become the new de-facto standard for text files) and always use UTF-8 when reading files.

How to save your JSON file as UTF-8? That depends on your text editor. In Notepad, for example, there's an "Encoding" drop-down box at the bottom of the "Save As" window.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I wondered why äöü wouldn't be included in unicode, and i haven't checked the files itself

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn: äöü *are* included in Unicode. The problem is that äöü are *also* included in the (much more limited) Latin-1 encoding, and, thus, your text editor tried to do you a favor and used the (old) Latin-1 encoding instead.

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn: In other words, your text editor saved `ä` as `E4` (= the Latin-1 encoding of `ä`) instead of `C3 A4` (= the UTF-8 encoding of `ä`). Now, trying to parse `E4` as UTF-8 results in an invalid result, which is why you get the Unicode error sign (aka "[replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block))": �) instead.